# Is the inclusion of Active Directory Groups in ArcGIS Server User management possible?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, authentication

I am currently installing ArcGIS server 10.3.1 to replace 10.0. I would like to base my user management on our organisation's Active Directory user list. It seems that I receive the total list of Active Directory users, but cannot filter according to user groups defined through an RDN Attribute.

Can anyone tell me if they have succesfully filtered users through a group in the Active Directory?

Comment: I've done it with both LDAP and ADFS on AWS and azure.  Are you using portal what specifically is the question?

Comment: Hi, my problem is that although I can get a list of all Active Directory users (approx.1000) ,I cannot define a new group within the active directory (for example GISUSERS) and set the parameters in ArcGIS Server to snychronize only these members so that they are imported into arcgis server. Specifically the parameters that were not being read were "dc" and "cn" . Either the paramters were not being read, or the sequence was incorrect.

Comment: The issue you are having with AD is an AD management issue.  To simplify the process you can use Server to manage users and roles instead of AD.

Comment: But then I would have to manually create all my new users which are already present in the Active Directory, wouldn´t I? = more work

Comment: That is correct.  If that does not work for you.. Your question is more AD specific than Server related.  What have you tried to do to create a new group and what fails? "cannot define a new group" please elaborate. Can you edit your question with those details?